# How to make the simplest jq filter query work?

Tags: json, jq, quotes, jsonpath

A very simple

```
echo '{"nodes":[{"id":"1"}]}' | jq '.nodes[?(@.id=="1")]'
```

fails due to

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '?' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.nodes[?(@.id=="1")]       
jq: 1 compile error
```

The hint "Unix shell quoting issues?" doesn't apply because everything is `'` quoted. However, I tried various unnecessary combinations of simple and double quotes and escaped versions thereof combined with escaping of `[`, `[`, `@` and `?`.

`echo '{"nodes":[{"id":"1"}]}' | jq '.nodes'` works as does `echo '{"nodes":[{"id":"1"}]}' | jq '.nodes[0]'`, so the error must be in the filter expression which is very simple, seen like this in dozens of examples and which I'm using in integration tests with the [Jayway JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

I'm using jq 1.6 on Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Since you have jq installed, you might want to review “jq for JSONPath Users” (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/For-JSONPath-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### [jsonpath](/questions/tagged/jsonpath) isn't the same as [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

---

The filter, `'.nodes[?(@.id=="1")]'` is in [JsonPath syntax](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators).

---

> How to make the simplest **jq** filter query work?

Change it to a [JQ select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.4/#example18) like so:

```
jq '.nodes[] | select(.id == "1")'
```

Where

- `.nodes[]` loops over all the nodes
- `select(.id == "1")` only keep the objects were `id === 1`

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ky1JC46MXC)